# InfluxDB Error: default retention policy not set for database in grafana after influx update from 1 to 2

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql, influxdb-2

I have updated my Influx database and also mapped the databases. But now I get the following problem in Grafana:

- InfluxDB Error: default retention policy not set for database
- InfluxDB Error: not executed

What could be the reason? I get the values via Flux without any problems. However, I would like to continue using InfluxQL

Answer (score 1):

In order to continue using InfluxQL you will need to setup the [Database/Retention Policy mapping](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/reference/api/influxdb-1x/dbrp/) for your new 2.x buckets, so that InfluxQL can treat them like 1.x databases. Have you done this already?

Answer (score 1):

Docs to refer:
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/influxql/dbrp/#create-dbrp-mappings

Example:

```
influx v1 dbrp create --default --bucket-id 520047e21111111 --db telegraf --rp default
```

I think you may change `default` to `autogen` (last parameter). I used `default` as it is used by Grafana 9? (Not confirmed). You see this in your error message:

> InfluxDB Error: **default** retention policy not set for database

Of course you need create such mapping for each bucket you have.

---

Maybe you will find it also useful example connection Grafana 9.1 -> Influx 2.4.

[image]

See `Configure InfluxDB authentication:`: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.1/tools/grafana/?t=InfluxQL

In this format you need to pass `Authorization` header. With space in it!

```
Token y0uR5uP3rSecr3tT0k3n
```

You can generate token in Influx web GUI (it will be long and i think Base64 encoded?)

[image]